# Php Json Get Value Array Index?

Tags: php, arrays, json, indexing

I have this code:

```
{"DT_RowId":"row_8","siparisler":{"id":"8","tarih":"14-12-2015","uid":"118","mid":"4","satis_fiyati":"5","adet":"7","odeme":"1","olusturan":"ares","sonduzenleyen":""},"urunler":{"urun_adi":"BANNER 100 AH","stok_kodu":"10010"},"musteriler":{"unvan":"3A Otomotiv San. Tic. Ltd. \u015eti."},"kdvsiz":"4.23728813559","kdv":"0.762711864407","top":"35"}
```

How can get `siparisler` id with array index?

```
$result2 = json_decode ($val,true);
return $result2[1][0];
```

I want to get that with array index because my JSON names are always different.

or how can i get second array name for if control ?

Comment: json_decode return StdClass

Comment: `result2["siparisler"]["id"]`

Comment: Yes Andrew but my siparisler name always differnt i need get with array index

Comment: or i need second array name for if control ?

Comment: or maybe use a static index name before `json_encode`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could use [`array_values()`](http://php.net/array-values) to normalize the arrays:

```
return array_values(array_values(json_decode($val, true))[1])[0];
```

> **array_values()** returns all the values from the `array` and indexes the array numerically.

The same split into multiple statements to be more clear:

```
$result = json_decode($val, true);
$result = array_values($result)[1];
$result = array_values($result)[0];
return $result;
```

---

Or for PHP 5.3 and below:

```
$result = json_decode($val, true);
$result = array_values($result);
$result = array_values($result[1]);
return $result[0];
```

Comment: This code right ? coz I keep getting error ? Thank you

Comment: are you using an outdated PHP version? Array dereferencing (`func()[]`) was introduced in 5.4

Comment: 5.3 is no longer supported. Please consider updating to at least 5.5

Comment: Nonetheless, I updated the answer with a solution for 5.3

Comment: Thank you, you are awesome.

Comment: can i ask you latest question can i get second array name like siparisler ?

Comment: Use `array_keys` instead of `array_values` to get the keys (the "names" as you say)